# How to integrate AWS Aurora RDS with Android

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds

I have searched all over the internet but couldn't find the answer to it. I want to use aurora as it is cheaper and better than DynamoDB of AWS so is there any way i can use android sdk to connect with aurora rds or simple MySql rds with mobile application. Thanks!

**Edit:**

Note : I don't want to connect database directly with the mobile application, just want to know the procedure of how to use RDS by AWS with Android or IOS version

and by Cheaper I meant what i read from a blog,
https://abhishek-tiwari.com/dynamodb-or-aurora/

It says:

> With a 50/50 read/write ratio, we expect 130,000 throughput per second. That will be 65,000 read or write per second just for 3340$ per month using the largest Aurora instance. Now to achieve the same kind of throughput with strong consistency, Amazon DynamoDB will cost you about 39,995$ per month. **That means DynamoDB throughput is 11 times more costly than Aurora**. In a nutshell, Aurora throughput is super cost effective.

Comment: You start with a false premise ("dynamodb is better than aurora") and it goes downhill from there. I read that link you provided and sadly the author also doesn't seem to know what he's talking about. NoSQL vs RDBMS is a horses for courses issue, not a "one is better than the other". What's your use case?! Others have already pointed out the very bad idea of connecting directly to an Internet expose database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good that you didn't find the answer.

**tl;dr: Don't attempt to allow your application to *directly* connect to your database server.**

The reasons why this is a very bad idea are many, but the short version is that it exposes your database unnecessarily, it provides the client (which can never be trusted) with some form of database credentials, and it will not scale, because the client connections must either be persistent (each of which consumes some amount of finite server resources, even when idle) or must be repeatedly created and destroyed (very inefficient).

To use Aurora, other RDS variants, or any similar database from an application, you need to create and expose a web service API that allows the application to perform authorized actions against your database.

Historically, this would have been done with application servers, but an example of how you might do this "serverless" would be to create one or more Lambda functions for interpreting JSON requests from the application, encapsulating the appropriate logic,  connecting to the database, and rendering JSON responses for the application to consume... and using API Gateway to expose the Lambda function to the Internet for authenticated access by the application.

Comment: Actually, I'm new to AWS and got to know that Aurora is better than Dynamo in some perspective https://abhishek-tiwari.com/dynamodb-or-aurora/  as explained in this blog, so i was wondering if there is a way i could use Aurora or MySql RDS with android as there is documentation for DynamoDB + Android, but nothing for RDS + Android

Comment: and i totally don't want to connect directly

Comment: RDS + Android implies a direct connection from the app to the DB... any other configuration means that RDS doesn't know about Android and Android doesn't know about RDS, because there is an abstraction layer in the middle.

Comment: Okay, so how should i proceed?

Comment: That's what I described in the answer.  You design an abstraction layer, such as with Lambda and API Gateway.

Comment: okay, i have just one more question. Do i have to create lambda functions for every read and write to different locations in RDS and if yes, won't it be too much of work, whereas for DynamoDB we can interact with it without lambda functions required through android sdk by aws.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-nosql-database.html#add-aws-mobile-nosql-database-crud-read

Comment: But for developmental purposes to initially fill a database one could want to connect directly to the database. I want to connect to the database directly with a DEV application and not have to write an API call just to simply record some data. Would you in this case still expect me to write all the API calls? (From my previous experience with a company, internally we just connected directly to the DB)

Answer (score 1):

Update the answer based on this edit of the OP.

> Note : I don't want to connect database directly with the mobile
>   application, just want to know the procedure of how to use RDS by AWS
>   with Android or IOS version

Develop some AWS Lambda functions using your programming language of choice and connect to the RDS instance.

Go with Amazons [Serverless Application Model (SAM)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/serverless_app.html) to expose API Gateway endpoints to your mobile app. All endpoints are backed using the above mentioned Lambda function.

You can tweak timeouts, memory settings, caching etc to fit your requirements and protect the resources using different [Authorizers or user pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html).

Comment: Actually, I'm new to AWS and got to know that Aurora is better than Dynamo in some perspective abhishek-tiwari.com/dynamodb-or-aurora as explained this blog, given that:  "With a 50/50 read/write ratio, we expect 130,000 throughput per second. That will be 65,000 read or write per second just for 3340$ per month using the largest Aurora instance. Now to achieve the same kind of throughput with strong consistency, Amazon DynamoDB will cost you about 39,995$ per month. That means DynamoDB throughput is 11 times more costly than Aurora. In a nutshell, Aurora throughput is super cost effective."

Comment: I'm sorry to put this so harshly, but I do NOT think it's a good idea to throw what looks like a critical project with very high performance throughput requirements at somebody who is new to AWS. Don't go on SE in that case. Tell your company to hire some people who know this stuff!

Comment: Updated my answer based on your new information @SahajRana

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just sniping from the comments, I think it'd be fair to properly answer:

1. Define **your** use case. What kind of data are you going to store? Is it structured data or unstructured data? Is it streaming data? This specifies and directs you towards the correct data store to use. Which in the specific case of AWS means something like, Aurora (or other RDS engines), DynamoDB, or even Kinesis, respectively. The latter isn't even a data store engine, but it shows that your data determines what you should use.
2. Others have already pointed out that you should not expose your DB directly. Whether you use an intermediate instance front-end, with the "usual" trappings, such as ELB, EC2, auto-scaling, or you just want an API front-end, which would direct you towards API Gateway.
3. It sounds like your company is throwing you in at the deep end expecting you to learn to swim in a rough ocean current. I strongly advise to get some training, including hands-on. Whether that takes you down the certification path is up to you, but you need to get enough basics down to even understand the plethora of moving parts in AWS. It can be utterly bewildering!

**Sadly, this answer in almost no way whatsoever directly relates to the actual topic in the question!** I gave it anyway, because I think it's important that you go back to actual basics so that you can rephrase the problem and the question better.

Comment: thanks for the wonderful answer, i will take care of that. Actually, the scenerio was that i used to use firebase, than we decided that it doesnt meets our requirements so we thought to move to aws and here I'm understanding what's going on in it.